# SQLDelight Schema Generation Failing

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, sqldelight

I'm using SQLDelight on Android and started reading about [SQLDelight's Gradle DSL](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/native_sqlite/gradle/) so that I could generate a database schema and prepare for a small migration.

I've been working with pretty much all default configuration, so I added this very minimal `sqldelight` block to my `build.gradle`:

```
sqldelight {
    Database {
        schemaOutputDirectory = file("src/main/sqldelight")
    }
}
```

After I added this block, I noticed the `generate*DatabaseSchema` tasks show up in my Gradle task list as expected. However, when I run the `generateDebugDatabaseSchema` task it consistently fails with this exception:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugDatabaseSchema'.
> Please use the ObjectFactory.listProperty() method to create a property of type List<T>.
```

Is there more I need to include within the `sqldelight` block for things to work properly? Can `sqldelight` be on its own, or does it need to be moved inside of `android`, `buildscript`, or some other part of the build file for things to work?